# Select all text on focus in numbers fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an aspx text box with class `num_input`. This should allow only numbers and automatically add comma separator:

```
 $('.num_input').live("keyup", function () {       
     $(this).numeric();
     var num = $(this).val().replace(/(,)/g, '');
     $(this).val(num.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
 });
```

We have a new requirement to select all text when user navigates through others textbox using tab or placing a cursor in the text.

I tried to use

```
 $(this).select();
```

but it didn't work!!

Comment: `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, removed in 1.9. Please switch to `.on()`.

Comment: If the user navigates and has focus on another element, how can the text also be selected?

Answer (score 1):

Jquery's `select` function isn't at all dedicated to selecting the text.

If you need that, do

```
this.selectionStart = 0;
this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
```

You can easily define a function letting you select the text of a jQuery element :

```
$.fn.selectText = function(){
  this.each(function(){
    this.selectionStart = 0;
    this.selectionEnd = this.value.length;
  });
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/puvequbegu/1/)